# How to install a FindXXX.cmake to a correct location?

Tags: cmake

I am developing a library which uses CMake to control it. It would be good to provide a "FindXXX.cmake" which locates the library and header files. This file would enable the users to use the command "find_package(XXX)" to find my library.

However, I don't know how to install my lib's "FindXXX.cmake" to an correct location. I failed to find a CMake's build-in mechanism to install a "FindXXX.cmake". In addition, CMake's variable "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH" is a list of directories, so I cannot install according to that vairable because I cannot decide which specific directory to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the copy of CMake is installed to a standard location(i.e. use no prefix etc) then this can be done by placing the file in `/usr/share/cmake/Modules/` directory.

If you are going to supply a bundle probably you can add some commands to check if the cmake is available. if yes you can check for `cmake --system-information|grep _INCLUDED_SYSTEM_INFO_FILE` value from that to get modules directory.

Otherwise there's **no way** you can do that.

A workaround can be done i.e. if there is a binary in your bundle then you can add a command line option for placing this file.

Comment: What a sad answer!! Maybe I can just don't install it, and leave the hell to user.

Comment: I've gone a bit more deep but not sure if this will help! check my answer now